# What were the reasons for the completely different ending in the Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2 film?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, twilight, breaking-dawn

In the book, we know that eventually

> Bella, Edward, and Renesmee live in peace after the Volturi execute Irina and take their leave.

But in the movie, we discover that

> Bella dies in a fierce battle with Sam Uley leaving Renesmee to be raised by Edward and Jacob.

Why would they stray from the original ending in the film?

Comment: The world today doesn't believe in happy ending

Comment: Finally watched the movie and got to know that the question is wrong.

Comment: VoLTIZEi: Based on peoples comments I'd have to say this question does not show any research effort, is unclear or unhelpful. I'd say this is all three, unfortunately.

Comment: Related meta discussion http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/what-should-be-done-to-the-question-which-contain-wrong-spoiler

Comment: This is not how the movie ends, as per Wikipedia. Voting to close, this seems like a troll.

Answer (score 12):

Um, I'm pretty sure that's not how the movie ends... Alice has a vision that shows how it *could* end, with everyone dying, including many of the Volturi. She shows the Volturi who choose to go on their way and leave Bella, Renesmee and Edward healthy and happy...